# ImportError: No module named 'nose'

Tags: python, installation, importerror, nose

I tried to help('modules') and there was no nose module.

I even tried pip install nose, sudo pip install nose, and etc..

When ever I tried to install nose with command line, it will throw out

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\plot_cluster_iris.py", line 31, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\spectral.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_random_state, as_float_array
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array, check_arrays, safe_asarray,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .fixes import safe_copy
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .testing import ignore_warnings
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py", line 36, in <module>
    from nose.tools import assert_equal
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you installing the right version of nose, suitable for your version of python?

Comment: I think so.. I install module for python34.. 
To be honest.. I am not sure what this nose actually is.. 
I just downloaded sklearn, numpy, and matplotlib for k mean clustering..

Comment: If you don't know what it is, why are you trying to install it?

Comment: nose is a testing framework that many packages use. Does pip point to python3 or do you need to use `pip3 install nose`

Comment: i just installed sklearn, numpy, and matlplotlib 
I did not type any word close to nose but above error showed up .. 
That is why I am trying to install whatever nose is..
Right now because of that error, i cannot see any output

Comment: I just tried pip3 install nose, however, it is still giving me a syntax error message. What did I do wrong..

Comment: You may need to uninstall and reinstall if you have an invalid installation.

Comment: Which one should I uninstall it? pip? three moduels? or the whole python :(

Comment: just the packages, pip3 uninstall nose numpy scikit-learn scipy and then reinstall, make sure you are installing in the right python environment. Virtualenv's are very good to isolate package dependencies.

Comment: I created a new Python3 virtualenv, pip3 install nose, and still I am getting the same error. Worse, I can do `python3 -c "from nose.tools import assert_raises"` without error.

Answer (score 4):

I think your `pip3` and `python3` versions are mismatched, possibly due to multiple versions of Python 3 installed.

Run `pip3 --version` to find the exact Python version that pip3 is associated with and the location of site-packages directory.

Then, run `python3` and look at the location of site-packages using:

```
import site
site.getsitepackages()
```

If you see different directory locations then that's your problem - multiple versions of Python 3. If it is indeed the problem, remove both the versions, re-install the correct one and then install your packages.

I hope this helps!